# how to get a parent object in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I have an object in javascript:

```
{
    name: "General",
    icon: "general",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Line 1",
        icon: "line",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Area 1",
            icon: "area",
            children: [
              { name: "Y", icon: "x" },
              { name: "Z", icon: "z" },
            ],
          },
          { name: "Area 2", icon: "line" },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Line 2,
        icon: "line",
        children: [{ name: "Area 3", icon: "area" }],
      },
    ],
  },
```

I am trying to do hierarchical structure filtering. After entering the name of the node in the search input, the hierarchical structure should disappear and a div should appear with the name of the node and the path in the hierarchy e.g. searche: Area 1,

Area1      |       General -> Line1.

Is there any way to get information about an object that is a parent in a structure?
Or should I just give each element an id and a parenId to refer to the parent

Comment: Do you mean you want to search for objects that have children? You could do that with `filter()`

Comment: Can you please provide details of the issue you're trying to solve, as this seems to be an X/Y question, where you're asking about a flawed solution instead of giving details of the problem itself.

Comment: If you mean, for example, that given a reference to the object with name "Area 1" can you find its parent named "Line 1", then no, you can't do that unless "Area 1" has a reference to "Line 1" (or you search through the object looking for child/parent relationships until you find the one you want).

Comment: Ok thank you. I was looking to see if there was any way without specifying the id everywhere.